# Запятая или тире в СПП?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Какую пунктуацию поставить в предложении:
"Насколько реально, а не мнимо это положение (,или -) зависит от успеха деятельности всей госсистемы"?

Answer (score 2):

Допустимы оба варианта. По классическому правилу-запятая, если хочется подчеркнуть придаточное изъяснительное, выделить его паузой - тире:
 Насколько реально, а не мнимо это положение , зависит от успеха деятельности всей госсистемы.
Насколько реально, а не мнимо это положение  -  зависит от успеха деятельности всей госсистемы. 
Я бы поставила тире.

Answer (score 0):

ПАС Лопатина: 
§ 124. В сложноподчиненном предложении ***может ставиться тире***:
1) после придаточной части, ***стоящей перед главной частью*** (особенно при наличии слов это, вот, то в главной части): Когда тоска — хорошо писать (Пауст.); Что в воздухе хлябь — на то уже не обращалось внимания (Ч.); Когда это кричит орел, сокол, ястреб, наконец, — это и красиво и мощно (М. Г.);
[здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=399#pg399)

**В Вашем примере можно поставить и запятую, и тире** (по правилу, изложенному выше). После придаточной в главной части можно вставить и ЭТО: "Насколько реально, а не мнимо это положение - [это] зависит от успеха деятельности всей госсистемы."